# Create a random border in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

I create a random number and on each pageload, the border-radius of my div is changing:

```
<script>
$(".card-body").each(function(){
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
$(this).css( {  borderRadius:  rand } );
});
</script>
```

How can I set the border radius like in this css?

```
border-radius: 255px 15px 225px 15px/15px 225px 15px 255px;}
```

Comment: You are trying to set random border radius or static?

Comment: if you need 8 different values why your code generates just one random value?

Comment: @fcalderan I don't think he wants just the three values as he's using `random`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code as below:

Loop 8 times and add(`+=`) to `rand` the number who random each time after the 4th number I added `/`

```js
$(".card-body").each(function(){
var rand="";
for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
{
 rand += Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1 + "px";
 if(i!=3)
  rand +=" ";
 else
   rand +="/ ";
 }
$(this).css( {  borderRadius:  rand } );
});
```

```css
.card-body-static{
border:1px solid black;
border-radius: 255px 15px 225px 15px/15px 225px 15px 255px;
margin-bottom:15px;
}

.card-body{
border:1px solid black;
margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body-static">static</div>

<div class="card-body">random</div>
<div class="card-body">random 2</div>
```

Comment: Hey, awesome work, thank you. Just one question: 255 / 225 is always fix. It should be something like: $(this).css( {  borderRadius:  random(250-255) random(10-15) random(250-255) random(10-15)/random(10-15) random(250-255) random(10-15) random(250-255) } ); - is it possible to create a string in the border-radius? Or should it - somehow - happen before?

Comment: Yes you can create a string and each time add the random if you want "hard coded" number add it to string

Comment: Last question: Now I have for each "card-body" item the same border. Is it possible to create for each "card-body" item a different border? What do I have to google?

Comment: it will create diffrent border each time see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can approach this problem, it involves constructing an array of `border-radius` values and then joining them to make up the string CSS rule.

1. Create a function that returns  a random number between 1 and 100 :

   ```
   function randomPercentage(){
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
   }
   ```
2. For each card, get its width

   ```
   $(".card-body").each(function(){

       const width = $(this).width();

      // ...

   });
   ```
3. Then create a new array containing two numbers (`[ 0, 0 ]`) :

   ```
   $(".card-body").each(function(){

       const width = $(this).width();

       const borderRadiusStyle = [0,0];

       // ...

   });
   ```
4. We need to map this array several time to get an array `border-radius` values. First assign a random percentage to each element (with the `randomPercentage` function). Then assign each percentage to a value by multiplying it by the width of the object (this is a good reference value for our `border-radius`). Another map will concatenate the value with the `'px'` string. Finally, we will join the two elements together with a space in between.

   ```
   $(".card-body").each(function(){

       const width = $(this).width();

       const borderRadiusStyle = [0,0];
         .map(value => randomPercentage())
         .map(percentage => width*percentage)
         .map(pixels => pixels + 'px')
         .join(' ');

       // ...

   });
   ```
5. You can then assign the property to the object :

   ```
   $(".card-body").each(function(){

       const width = $(this).width();

       const borderRadiusStyle = [0,0];
         .map(value => randomPercentage())
         .map(percentage => width*percentage)
         .map(pixels => pixels + 'px')
         .join(' ');

       $(this).css( {  borderRadius:  borderRadiusStyle });

   });
   ```

---

Here's the full code snippet:

```js
function randomPercentage(){
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}


$(".card-body").each(function(){
 
  const width = $(this).width();

 const borderRadiusStyle = [0,0]
    .map(value => randomPercentage())
    .map(percentage => width*percentage)
  .map(pixels => pixels + 'px')
    .join(' ');
    
 $(this).css( {  borderRadius:  borderRadiusStyle });
  
});
```

```css
.card-body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-body"></div>
<div class="card-body"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Ivan. Will have a look into your solution!